# How can i convert mireds to RGB or display mireds in css?

Tags: javascript, colors

From an application i get a color temprature in mireds, i want to display it in a HTML box but i cant find a way to display it via mireds. I thought there was an answer anywhere on the internet for displaying it or converting it. But, unfortunately not.

Does anyone know how i can convert or display it?

Regards,
Kuno

Answer (score 4):

The conversion you want to perform can be highly involved depending on the degree of precision required. Here is an outline of the algorithm and a *Python* implementation using [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour).

1. M (Mired) is the MIcro REciprocal Degree (Colour) Temperature **K** (Kelvin) thus the first step is the conversion from Mired to Kelvin as follows: *K = 1e6 / M*.
2. Then the Colour Temperature **K** can be converted to **CIE xy** Chromaticity Coordinates using a method such as [Kang et al. (2002)](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/f889c3cce3878a2e1d2882c4d446d158ef3069a5/colour/temperature/kang2002.py#L126) for simplicity or if extreme precision is required [Robertson (1968)](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/c8acc31a8507dae1af81d7958490ac3428dc2728/colour/temperature/robertson1968.py#L284) or [Ohno (2013)](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/5055477a9211819932bb11fb43cd98fee9797a78/colour/temperature/ohno2013.py#L380) (but this is much more involved to convert to Javascript).
3. Subsequently, the **CIE xy** Chromaticity Coordinates (equivalent to **CIE xyY** with Luminance set to 1) can be converted to [**CIE XYZ** Tristimulus Values](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/c8acc31a8507dae1af81d7958490ac3428dc2728/colour/models/cie_xyy.py#L116).
4. The **CIE XYZ** tristimulus values can be converted to **sRGB** Colourspace Values, at its simplest, it is a matrix multiplication using the [IEC 61966-2-1:1999 matrix](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/c8acc31a8507dae1af81d7958490ac3428dc2728/colour/models/rgb/datasets/srgb.py#L87).
5. The **sRGB** Colourspace Values are non-linearly encoded with the **[sRGB Inverse Electro-Optical Transfer Function](https://github.com/colour-science/colour/blob/c8acc31a8507dae1af81d7958490ac3428dc2728/colour/models/rgb/transfer_functions/srgb.py#L51)**.
6. Finally, the non-linear **sRGB** Colourspace Values are converted to hexadecimal. Note that the colours will overflow an 8-bit container thus you will need to normalise them.

Python Implementation ([Live Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NRcdXSCshivkwoU2nieCvC3y14fx1X4X#scrollTo=UDNY_mSem0Rr&line=3&uniqifier=1))

```python
import colour
import colour.plotting
import numpy as np


def CCT_to_mired(K):
    return 1e6 / colour.utilities.as_float_array(K)


def mired_to_CCT(M):
    return 1e6 / colour.utilities.as_float_array(M)


M = CCT_to_mired(
    ['2000', '3000', '4000', '5000', '6000', '7000', '8000', '9000'])

K = mired_to_CCT(M)
xy = colour.CCT_to_xy(K, method='Kang 2002')
XYZ = colour.xy_to_XYZ(xy)
RGB = colour.XYZ_to_sRGB(XYZ)
# Note that the colours are overflowing 8-bit, thus a normalisation
# process must be used.
RGB /= np.max(RGB, axis=1)[..., np.newaxis]

colour.plotting.plot_multi_colour_swatches(
    [colour.plotting.ColourSwatch(RGB=np.clip(x, 0, 1)) for x in RGB])

print(colour.utilities.as_int_array(RGB / np.max(RGB, axis=1)[..., None] * 255))
print(colour.notation.RGB_to_HEX(RGB))

# Conversion using the *Automatic Colour Conversion Graph*:
print(colour.convert(K, 'CCT', 'Hexadecimal', CCT_to_xy={'method': 'Kang 2002'}))
```

[image: Mireds to sRGB]

```
[[255 140  26]
 [255 184 110]
 [255 211 165]
 [255 230 207]
 [255 243 240]
 [244 242 255]
 [226 231 255]
 [214 223 255]]
['#ff8c19' '#ffb86f' '#ffd3a5' '#ffe6cf' '#fff3f0' '#f4f2ff' '#e2e7ff'
'#d6dfff']
['#ff8c19' '#ffb86f' '#ffd3a5' '#ffe6cf' '#fff3f0' '#f4f2ff' '#e2e7ff'
'#d6dfff']
```

Comment: Not at all an expert, but shouldn't the `CTT_to_mired()` and `mired_to_CTT()` be "one million over X", not 10 million (i.e. `1e6`, not `10e6`)? See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mired) " The constant 1000000 K is one million kelvins."

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick-and-dirty solution in Python (+ numpy). It's very suitable to convert in cases when you don't really need too much accuracy, but the general idea should be preserved:

```
import numpy as np

def mired_to_rgb(mired):
    """
    Quick and dirty, returns r, g, b tuple (all between 0 and 1)
    """
    M2RGB = MIRED_RGB.T
    r = np.interp(mired, M2RGB[0], M2RGB[1])
    g = np.interp(mired, M2RGB[0], M2RGB[2])
    b = np.interp(mired, M2RGB[0], M2RGB[3])
    return r, g, b


MIRED_RGB = np.array([
        [   0, 0x86, 0xAE, 0xFF],
        [ 100, 0xBC, 0xD8, 0xFF],
        [ 200, 0xFE, 0xFC, 0xFF],
        [ 300, 0xFF, 0xED, 0xB6],
        [ 400, 0xFF, 0xD8, 0x77],
        [ 500, 0xFF, 0xC1, 0x40],
        [ 600, 0xFF, 0xA8, 0x00],
        [ 700, 0xFF, 0x90, 0x00],
        [ 800, 0xFF, 0x76, 0x00],
        [ 900, 0xFF, 0x59, 0x00],
        [1000, 0xFF, 0x39, 0x00],
        [1050, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00],
    ]) / [1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF]
```

I took the known colour values for some mireds (literally by using a colour picker on the colours in the image on the [Mired wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mired)). Then I interpolate, by interpolating separately the R, G and B values (as I said, only a rough approximation).

If you want the thing to return values between 0 and 255, remove the `/ [1, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF]` at the end.

Using `numpy`'s [`interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) to interpolate, but it shouldn't be hard to remove this dependency and make your own `interp()`.

---

UPDATE: I later found [Tanner Helland's algorithm here](https://tannerhelland.com/2012/09/18/convert-temperature-rgb-algorithm-code.html), since it was included in [the Matter example code](https://github.com/project-chip/connectedhomeip/blob/4088a77f557e8571a39338fad51a1d8eb0131d79/examples/lighting-app/lighting-common/src/ColorFormat.cpp#L134)